# Jcrop and IE9 Image File is Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, jcrop

For some reason, IE9 has decided to have an issue with Jcrop and getting the data from the file to be uploaded. This line:

```
var oFile = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];
```

I'm getting: `Unable to get properly '0' of undefined or null reference`

At the end of the day, I need to be able to access the properties of the file... and IE9 doesn't seem to be able to function by asking for `[0].files[0]`

Answer (score 1):

IE9 has no such of property, [`files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property of `input type="file"` was introduced in IE10.

Comment: Okay, that definitely starts to help ... but what's the workaround?

Comment: Jcrop supports IE6+ ... I don't think it's Jcrops fault, but the line I commented on above: `var oFile = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];`

Comment: "`This page was last modified on 13 August 2008, at 19:41`" --> Jcrop doesn't necessarily support IE9 : ).

Comment: The bottom line is that I need an object for the file ... so I can extract `size`, `type`, etc. That object is then passed like `oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);` to continue processing the request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Jcrop but for IE9-, there is a problem accessing the div with the id `image_file`

I use this code for loading the image into a variable:

```
 $('#image_file').change(function () {
                    var oFile = this.files[0];
          //...
    });
```

Comment: It's this functionality that's the issue in IE9: `var oFile = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];`